# Mock Injected Service In Unit Testing Nest.js

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I would like to test my service (Location Service). In this Location Service, I inject repository and other service called GeoLocationService, but got stuck when I am trying to mock this GeoLocationService.

It throws me an error

```
GeolocationService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GeolocationService (?). Please make sure that the argument HttpService at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

Here is the provider's code

```
@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('LOCATION_REPOSITORY')
    private locationRepository: Repository<Location>,

    private geolocationService: GeolocationService, // this is actually what I ma trying to mock
  ) {}

  async getAllLocations(): Promise<Object> {
return await this.locationRepository.find()
  }
....
}
```

Here is the test code

```
describe('LocationService', () => {
  let service: LocationService;
  let repo: Repository<Location>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [GeolocationModule],
      providers: [
        LocationService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Location),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<LocationService>(LocationService);
    repo = module.get<Repository<Location>>(getRepositoryToken(Location));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of adding `imports: [GeolocationModule]` you should provide a mock of `GeolocationService`. This mock should have the same method names as the `GeolocationService`, but they can all be stubbed (`jest.fn()`) or they can have some return values (`jest.fn().mockResolved/ReturnedValue()`). Generally, the custom provider (added to the `providers` array) would look like this:

```js
{
  provide: GeolocationService,
  useValue: {
    method1: jest.fn(),
    method2: jest.fn(),
  }
}
```

[You can find a large sample of mocks in this repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs).

Comment: why do we not import modules? isn't service part of the module?

Comment: When you add `imports: [SomeModule]`, then if `SomeModule` has other imports you need to take care to have those available in the test context as well, and then those import's imports and so on down the chain. By just adding the service, you know exactly what dependencies are needed to be provided, and can provide basic mocks without going further into dependency hell